# Rails Submitting Multiple Has_Many Attributes via Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am running a Rails 5.1 app with the following information:

Models

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :complaints
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :complaints
  validates :name, presence: true
end

class Complaint < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  validates :username, :priority, presence: true
end
```

Controller

```
class ComplaintController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @company = Company.new
    @company.complaints.build
  end

  def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @company.save
        format.html { redirect_to complaint_url }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def company_params
      params.require(:company).permit(:name, complaints_attributes: [:username, :priority])
    end
```

Form in view

```
<%= form_for @company do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :name, "Company" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, type: "text" %>

  <%= f.fields_for :complaints do |complaint| %>

    <%= complaint.label :username, "Username" %>
    <%= complaint.text_field :username %>

    <%= complaint.label :priority, "Priority" %>
    <%= complaint.text_field :priority %>

  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

If I have just one input field for the `complaint_attributes` part of the form (in other words just one field for username and one field for priority as shown above), this works just fine.

However, if I want to have multiple fields for username/priority in the form, so that I can submit multiple username/priority combinations in a single submission, I find that submitting the form will only save the last username/priority values from the form.  Example of this view would be:

```
<%= form_for @company do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :name, "Company" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, type: "text" %>

  <%= f.fields_for :complaints do |complaint| %>

    <div>
      <%= complaint.label :username, "Username" %>
      <%= complaint.text_field :username %>

      <%= complaint.label :priority, "Priority" %>
      <%= complaint.text_field :priority %>
    </div>

    <div>
      <%= complaint.label :username, "Username" %>
      <%= complaint.text_field :username %>

      <%= complaint.label :priority, "Priority" %>
      <%= complaint.text_field :priority %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

I noticed that when submitting the form, I get a hash like this (for submitting single complaint):

`{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "company"=>{"name"=>"Test", "complaints_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"username"=>"test_person", "priority"=>"1"}}}, "commit"=>"Submit"}`

Is there any way to modify the params to make it similar to this and have it saved to the DB?:

`{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "company"=>{"name"=>"Test", "complaints_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"username"=>"test_person", "priority"=>"1"}"1"=>{"username"=>"test_person", "priority"=>"2"}}}, "commit"=>"Submit"}`

Or if not the above, what would be the best way to have the username/priority values saved if using multiple fields for them in a single form?

EDIT:  I should point out that I can dynamically add the username/priority field groups as needed, so I don't want to be restricted to a set number.

Comment: FYI your `EDIT` makes it a completely different question....

Comment: Yes - my apologies for not pointing that out.  I realized it as soon as the first answer was posted.

Answer (score 0):

the second block will override the first fields... you should instead build many complaints in the controller:

```
def new
  @company = Company.new
  3.times { @company.complaints.build }
end
```

and then with the following form it should generate to inputs according to the number of complaints you have built:

```
<%= form_for @company do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :name, "Company" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, type: "text" %>

  <%= f.fields_for :complaints do |complaint| %>

    <%= complaint.label :username, "Username" %>
    <%= complaint.text_field :username %>

    <%= complaint.label :priority, "Priority" %>
    <%= complaint.text_field :priority %>

  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried this, but the last block is still overriding the others, and therefore only the last block is saved.

EDIT:  Disregard - this works.  However, it pre-sets the number of fields.  What if I have a way to dynamically add the fields as needed (which I do)?

Comment: weird... can you let me know the params that arrive in your controller?

Comment: I edited my above comment.  It works, but what if I have dynamic fields?

Comment: ah ok, in that case you need to build it using js (to remove/add more associated objects).... there are a few gems that might help you with that... the most popular are https://github.com/ncri/nested_form_fields and https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Comment: Interesting...let me check those out and will let you know if those work for me.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: Hey gabrielhilal - I looked at both gems and tested.  I'm still not getting the exact result I need though.  I noticed the `nested_form_fields` gem is producing the hash I would like to see, but I don't like the implementation of how it adds/removes fields.  I'll keep doing some research as I'd rather not rely on a gem anyway.

Comment: @Wes I have code that handles dealing with the subforms, specifically the "add" and "remove" actions.  I've created a gist here: https://gist.github.com/mdchaney/8d8de28b6776ca3d14630e8771267a3c which has all the code.  I put that together from stuff that I found around, and I don't claim ownership of it.  It works wonderfully and I use it on nearly every single production site that I operate.

Comment: I ended up adjusting my dynamic field creation (jquery script) to create the proper name attribute values for each new field generated (the way that rails appears to do name attribute values for multiple fields).  This gives me the hash I was looking for, and makes it to where I don't need to make extensive changes to the app.